# Android gps permissions

Tags: android, gps

Hi guys/gals java neanderthal floundering again. I'm making an android app as part of my final project for college. This activity is about three activities in and it is the thumbnail image viewer after a picture is taken by camera/from gallery (which is working fine). The problem is displaying the gps co-ords which I will eventually send to a database with the picture. I was getting fatal errors due to runtime permissions not being handled (API 23+) which I found answers to and thought it was ok. However, I'm not crashing or generating any errors but I'm not getting the dialogue box looking for permissions, or the toasts telling me whether I have the permissions or not. I also can't set the text in the text view for the values. I would appreciate any help you could give me. Thanks in advance!
    package com.example.gary.natureallv2;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CameraPicActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 10;
    public static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;
    private ImageView ivPicSelected;
    private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    public final static int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    public final static int MINUTE = 60 * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 102;
    private boolean permissionIsGranted = false;
    private TextView tvLatValue;
    private TextView tvLongValue;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_pic);
        ivPicSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPicSelected);
        tvLatValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatValue);
        tvLongValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongValue);
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        //initialise the location request with the accuracy and frequency with which we want location updates
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(MINUTE);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15 * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }




    /**
     * Method called when btnFromCamera is clicked.
     * @param view
     */
    public void btnFromCameraClicked(View view){
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);//
//        String pictureName = getPictureName();//
//        File imageFile = new File(pictureDirectory, pictureName);//
//        Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);//
//        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);//
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked when the user presses the From Gallery button.
     * @param view
     */
    public void onBtnGalleryClicked(View view){
        //Invoke the image gallery with an implicit intent.
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        //Where to find the data.
        File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();
        //get a Uri representation.
        Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath);
        //set the data and type/get all image types.
        photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);


    }

    private String getPictureName() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String timeStamp = sdf.format(new Date());
        return "natureall" + timeStamp +".jpg";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                Bitmap cameraImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ivPicSelected.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);


            }
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST){
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                //declare a stream to read the image data.
                InputStream inputStream;
                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    ivPicSelected.setImageBitmap(image);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open the image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){requestLocationUpdates();}

    private void requestLocationUpdates(){
          if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
                return;
            }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }




    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (permissionIsGranted) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (permissionIsGranted) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    permissionIsGranted = true;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    permissionIsGranted = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tvLatValue.setText("Lat permission denied");
                    tvLongValue.setText("Long permission denied");
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (permissionIsGranted){
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected())
            requestLocationUpdates();
    }}


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(permissionIsGranted) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (permissionIsGranted){
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed:" + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            tvLongValue.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
            tvLatValue.setText(Double.toString(latitude));



        }
    }

}



`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the permissions to the android manifest outside the application tag

and the others?